# Not able to use <extract-path> for element starts with digit e.g. <extract-path>/5DigitalNotes</extract-path> in MarkLogic

Tags: xml, search, xpath, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am not able to extract the element which starts with Digit e.g. 5DigitalNotes in MarkLogic  search options

I am trying to use below search options

```
<options>
    <extract-document-data>
            <extract-path>/5DigitalNotes</extract-path>
    </extract-document-data>
</options>
```

But it returns following error.

```
<error-response><status-code>400</status-code><status>Bad Request</status><message-code>XDMP-UNEXPECTED</message-code><message>XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected AlmostNumeric_, expecting Function30_ or Percent_</message></error-response>
```

where for testing as well when i have used below query

```
cts.validExtractPath("/5DigitalNotes")
```

it returns False.
Surprisingly below works

```
cts.validExtractPath("/The5DigitalNotes")
```

it returns True.

Could anyone let me know how can i extract such kind of elements using  MarkLogic  search options? I dont have option to changes the field name from stored documents so need to find out the workaround only.

Answer (score 3):

XML elements cannot have names starting with digits. Those are non-wellformed. If you have JSON properties with such names, try using `/node("5DigitalNotes")` instead, a trick also useful for other characters in names not expected by XPath, like spaces..

HTH!

Comment: Thank you much for this work around. Yes it's on JSON property.